# How to make method generic when using inheritance in Java?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I have class `Employee` and 3 classes that extends `Employee` class.
I also have `EmployeeService` interface where i want to have only one `save` method to handle saving each type of Employee. So i assumed that it could be solved using generics.
This is what i tried in `EmployeeService` interface:

```
public interface EmployeeService {
<SubRequestT extends  Employee>EmployeeResponse save(SubRequestT requestT);
}
```

And class that provide implementation:

```
@Service
public class EmployeeServiceImpl implements EmployeeService {

// So here in argument i want to have to put any kind of Employee, for example:
@Override
public EmployeeResponse save(OfficeEmployee requestT) {
// Logic for saving employee
    return null;
}
}
```

But when i changed from `Employee` type to any other, for example `OfficeEmployee` who is extending from Employee, complier is giving me an error. What is best way to solve this?

Comment: What's wrong with using Employee?

Answer (score 2):

With "method generics" I (me & compiler) also struggle, but with "type generics" we can do that!

Assuming:

```
class Foo {/*...*/}

class Bar extends Foo {}

class Baz extends Foo {}

// extending your question to two generic parameters:
class FooResult {}

class BarResult extends FooResult {}

class BazResult extends FooResult {}
```

When we define our interface like:

```
interface FooI<I extends Foo, R extends FooResult> { //or with even more (fixed size) "generic parameters"
  R save(I request);
}
```

We can override it like:

```
class BarImpl implements FooI<Bar, BarResult> {
  @Override
  public BarResult save(Bar bar) {
    // ...
    return ...;
  }
}

class BazImpl implements FooI<Baz, BazResult> {
  @Override
  public BazResult save(Baz baz) {
    // ...
    return ...;
  }
}
```